# How to join push notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the Gcm Intent Service to receive and send notifications to the device. I have a lot of notification types, diferentiated by a type id.

My intention is to join/combine/merge/update the notifications if exists more than one of any type.

For example, join 2 notifications like this:

> Notification 1: "Peter added you"
>
> Notification 2: "Sara added you"
>
> Join RESULT: "2 users added you"

How can I do that? How can I detect if there are any active notification and get the action number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by saving the notification ID and reusing that ID you can update the notification:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating